# How to selectively enable or disable SSL for some URLs in Tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat, ssl

```
<pre>   1. I am using SSL in Tomcat 7, create a keystore and configure server.xml, and also config in web.xml as below 
 <b>   <security-constraint>
            <web-resource-collection>
                <web-resource-name>SSL</web-resource-name>
                <url-pattern>/inspectionGp/*</url-pattern>
                <url-pattern>/inspection/*</url-pattern>
                <url-pattern>/inspGpDt/*</url-pattern>
                <url-pattern>/inspDt/*</url-pattern>
            </web-resource-collection>
            <user-data-constraint>
                <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
            </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
```

2. That works for SSL, these restricted URLs are forced to use only SSL, but other URLs can also use both HTTP and HTTPS, it's strange, I don't want use HTTPS for the URLs which are not configured in . I use  NONE, that will result in all URLs support both HTTP and HTPPS. So can anybody help explain how I can resolve it?

```
   3. And another issue, why other the links are https when I click the url which only support https
```

Answer (score 0):

The transport guarantee is a minimum level the connection must meet. Therefore it is perfectly valid to use TLS if the minimum transport guarantee is NONE.

If you want to force switching back to TLS then you'll need to explicitly code this. Options include:

- Explicitly use http in links to pages you want to use http for
- Write a filter that redirects to http and map it to the URLs you want to use for http